# Bluetooth issues/crash on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, 20.04, bluetooth, hp, amd-ryzen

I have a problem with the bluetooth (i'm using bluetooth headphones), on my laptop with a ryzen 2500u.

With windows everything works normally, on ubuntu randomly, the bluetooth "disables" itself and no longer works until the pc is restarted.

This is the output of dmesg:

```
[  330.067339] wlo1: deauthenticating from 44:33:4c:c9:05:10 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  330.067751] rtw_8723de 0000:03:00.0: sta 44:33:4c:c9:05:10 with macid 0 left
[  330.128712] rtw_8723de 0000:03:00.0: stop vif 90:32:4b:86:2e:31 on port 0
[  683.474765] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: Mismatch between completed Set TR Deq Ptr command & xHCI internal state.
[  683.474770] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: ep deq seg = 00000000d7f2423c, deq ptr = 00000000894a44d2
[  684.475727] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000e address=0x0 flags=0x0000]
[  689.572240] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[  689.572244] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: USBSTS: HCHalted HSE
[  689.572266] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[  689.572285] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: HC died; cleaning up
[  689.572336] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  689.572340] usb 3-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  689.616385] usb 3-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  690.919221] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[  695.016159] rtw_8723de 0000:03:00.0: start vif 90:32:4b:86:2e:31 on port 0
[  696.379705] wlo1: authenticate with 44:33:4c:c9:05:10
[  696.635899] wlo1: send auth to 44:33:4c:c9:05:10 (try 1/3)
[  696.637405] wlo1: authenticated
[  696.640363] wlo1: associate with 44:33:4c:c9:05:10 (try 1/3)
[  696.647969] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 44:33:4c:c9:05:10 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[  696.647994] rtw_8723de 0000:03:00.0: sta 44:33:4c:c9:05:10 joined with macid 0
[  696.648341] wlo1: associated
[  697.158251] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
```

Seems a problem on the USB controller ???
I would like to use linux only, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `iommu=soft` kernel parameter.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer so that people know where to put the kernel parameter and perhaps a bit about what this will do?